# Discrete Probability - Probability of Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

Hey guys, I need some help with this problem. So they want us to find a) and b). So I know by definition Probability of B Complement is $1 - P(B)$.

So $P(\overline{B}) = 1 - 0.73 = 0.24$. How can I use this to find $P(\overline{B} \cap C)$?

Comment: Try drawing a Venn diagram for your events, formulas might become clearer

Comment: B complement Intersect C is just C - B, but P(C) - P(B) = -.03 which can't be right...

Comment: It isn't $P(C)$ - $P(B)$. It is $P(C) - P(B\cap C)$. If you are starting with area of $C$ than you can only subrtract parts of that area, you cannot subtract something that isn't part of $C$.

Comment: Why? I drew a venn diagram, and I see that B complement intersect C is the same as C - B? Why is it not C - B but instead C - (B intersect C)?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://imgur.com/a/dtisZep), I hope it helps.

Comment: So although they are technically equivalent in terms of Venn Diagram, we cannot express it as C - B because B is not part of C? But only B $\cap$ C is part of C?

Comment: You are correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: a) $$\overline{B}\cap C = C\setminus (B\cap C)$$

So $$P(\overline{B}\cap C) = P(C)-P(B\cap C)=...$$

b) Use formula inclusion/exclusion

Comment: Wait, isn't(B complement $\cap$ C) just equal to B - C?

Comment: Yeah...............................

Comment: so P(C) - P(B) = 0.24 - 0.27 = -0.3... but that can't be right because probability of any event must be greater than 0?